# cannot read json pass from php file by jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
  [{
      p_date: "26-07-2013",
      c_no: "1",
      time_slot: "shift1"
  }]

   $.each(data, function (i, elem) {


      alert(elem[p_date]);

  });
```

i get above json from my php file.all i want to do is read it from  jquery file.I tried above method to read that json .but it didn't work.

```
      i get the following error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't `elem[p_date]` be `elem["p_date"]` in your each function? Or you could also try `elem.p_date`.

```
 var data = [{
     p_date: "26-07-2013",
     c_no: "1",
     time_slot: "shift1"
 }]

 $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
     alert(elem["p_date"]);
     //or elem.p_date would also work.
 });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/c46br/

**Edit :**

If you get the following error message,

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '77' in [{p_date: "26-07-2013" , c_no: "1", time_slot: "shift1" } ]

It means your (so-called) JSON is a string. You'll have to do this :

```
var formatted = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then, you can use `formatted` variable in `each` :

```
$.each(formatted, function (i, elem) {
```

**PHP formatting** :

This is how you make an array in PHP:

```
$first = true;
$json = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($distributor_List)) {
  array_push($json, $row);
}
echo json_encode($json)
```

This will ensure that you neednt use `JSON.parse` in JS :)

Comment: this should actually work, unless `data` doesn't get filled as expected.. make sure of its content first

Comment: @Dilshi if it doesn't work then you haven't shown us the relevant code

Comment: @Dilshi pls make a fiddle for your problem. Then we'll know whats really wrong :)

Comment: function pop_search_prescription(param) {


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Patient_Handler.php",
        data: {
            search_pres: param


        },
        success: function(data) {
   
            $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
          alert(elem["p_date"]);
                
               
            });
        }
    });

Comment: above i get get the json to data variable.it works fine.but i cannot display it.

Comment: @Dilshi Try `console.log(data);` right before the `$.each` to see if first, it is an array. Second, is every occurences a json object? You should be able to list their properties in the object inspector. If not, that's the problem.

Comment: i get following error.caught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '77' in 

 [{p_date:  "26-07-2013" , c_no:  "1",  time_slot:  "shift1"        }   ]

Comment: hey i trie it.but now i get this.Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p

Comment: @Dilshi could you make a `console.log(data)` and post the results here? Something fishy going on here

Comment: @Dilshi post it in the question. Edit it. Dont post it in the comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34213/discussion-between-hungerpain-and-dilshi)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.each(data, function (i, elem) {
     alert(elem['p_date']); //notice the `''`
});
```

Comment: it works when i hardcode that string.but when i try to prin the same string taken from php .it gives folowing error.annot use 'in' operator to search for '77' in [{p_date: "26-07-2013" , c_no: "1", time_slot: "shift1" } ]